# Does sem_post wake up a random process

Tags: c, semaphore

Suppose 10 processes are waiting on a semaphore using sem_wait().
and an 11th process calls sem_post on that semaphore. 
which of the 10 processes will enter the critical block? 
Is it like random? All the process will wake up and strive to achieve a lock.
and CPU will provide a lock to one of the processes and the rest will go back to waiting for state

Comment: It's not the CPU, it's the OS (more precisely, the scheduler code within the OS kernel). And the answer to your question depends on the scheduling mode that the OS is configured to work in. For example, Round Robin in the case where all threads are of equal priority, will pick the thread which has been out of context for the longest period of time.

Comment: 'All the process will wake up and strive to achieve a lock' no.  There is no need for such gross inefficiencies.  The waiting threads are stored in a container in the semaphore, tree, queue, something).  If a signal arrives, a thread is popped off the container and made ready/running.

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX standard doesn't specify which thread will be woken up. Moreover, without artificial delays it's impossible for threads to start waiting on a semaphore in a well-defined order.

In practice, it's likely to be the thread which has been waiting the longest, as a queue structure is used to record threads waiting on a synchronization object. It definitely won't be a 'random' thread. But it's also not something you should depend on for the correctness of your code.